# How can I increase the JVM memory?

Tags: java, jvm

HI,
I like to know can I increase the memory of the JVM depending on my application.If yes how can I increase the JVM memory?
And how can I know the size of JVM?

Comment: In java 8 you don't have to do this, it is dependent on your main memory.

Answer (score 121):

When starting the JVM, two parameters can be adjusted to suit your memory needs :

```
-Xms<size>
```

specifies the initial Java heap size and

```
-Xmx<size>
```

the maximum Java heap size.

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0131.html

Comment: Do not forget to specify the unit of your size: 2048m, otherwise the JVM assumes you mean bytes...

Comment: `ms` stands for `minimal`, not for initial

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Eclipse then you can do this by specifying the required size for the particular application in its Run Configuration's VM Arguments as EX: `-Xms128m -Xmx512m`

Or if you want all applications running from your eclipse to have the same specified size then you can specify this in the `eclipse.ini` file which is present in your Eclipse home directory.

To get the size of the JVM during Runtime you can use `Runtime.totalMemory()` which returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine, measured in bytes.

Answer (score 12):

When calling java use the -Xmx Flag for example -Xmx512m for 512 megs for the heap size. You may also want to consider the -xms flag to start the heap larger if you are going to have it grow right from the start. The default size is 128megs.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Run As -> Run Configurations..-> Select Arguments tab -> In VM Arguments you can increase your JVM memory allocation. Java HotSpot document will help you to setup your VM Argument [HERE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

I will not prefer to make any changes into eclipse.ini as minor mistake cause lot of issues. It's easier to play with VM Args