# how to increase heap size of java cache memory

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I'm using berkeley db java edition (Base api) to insert 5 lack rows to db database I already inserted 1000 rows in 200 ms bt i m getting problem in inserting 5 lack rows so i think there is something some paramaeter to set in EnvironmentConfig class or dbconfig class

error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at WriteDataBase.main(WriteDataBase.java:29)
```

Comment: Increase heap size? Google is your friend http://tinyurl.com/6g3gvx9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in writing record to Berkeley DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549610/problem-in-writing-record-to-berkeley-db)  .... asked a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to increase the maximum heap size of your JVM.  Add `-Xmx512m` to your startup options.  For example, if your application is in a jar file:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar yourjarfile.jar
```

Or if you are executing the class directly:

```
java -Xmx512m com.whatever.YourClassName
```

The `512m` means to set a maximum heap size of 512 Megabytes.  That may be too big or too little, depending on your application, so you will need to experiment.