# Java Out of Memory Exception heap Space

Tags: java, jxl

I wrote code in java which reading one excel file and after encrypting data its writing againg. Code is working fine but when i am passing 12 mb size file to code its giving error

```
 Warning:  Usage of a local non-builtin name
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at jxl.read.biff.File.next(File.java:181)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.read(SheetReader.java:375)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.readSheet(SheetImpl.java:716)
    at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.getSheet(WorkbookParser.java:257)
    at ReadExcel.read(ReadExcel.java:41)
    at ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:162)`

How can i resolve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increase the JVM memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory)

Comment: i have done it but same error

Comment: how much did you try? And please add the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Post the block of code surrounding ReadExcel.java line 41. :P

Comment: @oers: i increased it 1024 mb

Comment: We can't help you, if you don't provide the relevant parts of the code.