# Java UUID's long representation

Tags: java, out-of-memory, uuid

I'm storing tons of Java `UUID` into a `HashMap` as row using `UUID.toString()`. Since the data is huge, soon it throws `OutOfMemoryError`. Now I'm thinking about a compact way to represent the `UUID`, preferably something like `long`, and then later I can easily reconstruct the `UUID` with that `long` representation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A UUID is fundamentally a number, but it's a 128-bit number, which is twice the size of a java long. You could use BigInteger (which is probably no more space-efficient than storing UUIDs as strings), or you could encapsulate the UUID in an object that contains two longs — one for the first 64 bits and one for the last 64 bits.

Given the UUID `550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000`, you would want to create two longs, one containing the number `0x550e8400e29b41d4`, and one containing the number `0xa716446655440000`.

Answer (score 9):

> I'm storing tons of Java `UUID` into a `HashMap` as row using `UUID.toString()`.

So by this you mean `HashMap<String, MyObject>`?

Storing UUID itself via `HashMap<UUID, MyObject>` will conserve space compared to `HashMap<String, MyObject>`. A `UUID` takes up less space than the `String` does (two `long` values become 16 bytes versus `char[36]` for 72 bytes, that'll save you almost 80% space right there).

If changing that's not enough, then consider whether or not the `UUID` values are important across JVM's. If the ID only needs to be unique for a single process (are you saving the `HashMap` to disk or sharing it *between* Java processes?), then you can just use `int` since a `HashMap` can't be any bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` anyway. So instead of `HashMap<UUID, MyObject>`, you'd have `HashMap<Integer, MyObject>`. Even better, you can use `Short` if you are going to have less than 2<sup>16</sup> objects, saving even more space. However, if you're getting an `OutOfMemoryError`, I suspect you probably have more than 65536 objects.

Lastly, if all else fails, allocate more memory to your JVM as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory).