# how to decrease jvm size when i launching eclipse in window

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have following configuration of my laptop -

2gb ram 
core i3 processor

So when i launching eclipse and run any program my laptop become slow.
that's why i want to reduce the jvm size.

So, how can I reduce the JVM memory ?

thnks

Comment: [How can I increase the JVM memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory)

Answer (score 2):

In your eclipse install folder, you have eclipse.ini file.In that file, you can specify the below mentioned arguments for the eclipse VM.

-Xms
-Xmx

Please note, here we are giving the memory arguments for running the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying the required size for the particular application in its Run Configuration's VM Arguments as EX: -Xms128m -Xmx512m

Or if you want all application run from your eclipse to have the same spacified size then you can specify this in the eclipse.ini file which is present in your Eclipse home directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of solutions if you google it, but in common, there is number of objects that influence to perfomance of your system at all:

- By default, Eclipse have standart options of JVM, so you not feel much performance increase if you tune your JVM, you also should disable validations and plugins which you not using (Ex.: spell-check and so on)
- You have small RAM, so, you can buy additional 2 or more RAM and increase perfomance too :) But with 2Gb of RAM - not expect, that your computer with running Eclipse will be fast (Eclipse require much ram for commfort work)
- Or another workaround - install more faster IDE: IDEA or Netbeans