# Reading .xlsx file using apache poi gives org.apache.poi.POIXMLException on linux machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-poi, xlsx

I have an application which reads an .xlsx file and displays the content to the user. The application works fine on a windows environment.

I deployed the .war file of this web app on tomcat6 on a ubuntu server. I also copied the .xlsx files on the server.

The path of the files in the code is correct.

But the line

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(FileName));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

gives an error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:207)
com.qm.action.GetProjectNames.execute(GetProjectNames.java:107)
```

I have checked that the variable FileName contains the correct path and filename of the files on server(/usr/local/Metrics/MetricFiles/FY2013_Q2_GIT_Review_Metrics_by_LSS-GC.xlsx)

Since the ubunut server is a VM, I had copied the .xlsx files using WinSCP. The size of the files is also correct.

Why is this error occurring on linux platform?

Adding the Additional exception trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) at 
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60) ... 68 more 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694) at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseCdataLiteral(PiccoloLexer.java:3027) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseQuotedTagValue(PiccoloLexer.java:2936) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1754) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4678) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1270) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1257) at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345) at 
org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source) at 
org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.readFrom(StylesTable.java:121) at 
org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.<init>(StylesTable.java:92) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) at 
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60) at 
org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403) at 
org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155) at 
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:207) at 
com.qm.action.GetProjectNames.execute(GetProjectNames.java:107) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
```

Comment: That looks to be the boring half of the exception... What was the rest of it? (The caused by part will tell you what really is the problem)

Comment: This Apache POI API is working fine for .xls files but seems issue with .xlsx file, I got similar exception while reading the .xlsx but able to read .xls file

Comment: @Satya .. Apache POI is working fine for .xlsx files on windows platform for me. Did you get this exception with apache poi on all platforms?

Comment: @Gagravarr . I have added the additional exception trace. It suggests out of memory exception. The file I am reading is about 1MB. Will reading a file of this size also give java heap space error?

Comment: Did you try increasing your heap size? That's the normal fix if you haven't given Java enough memory...

Comment: @Gagravarr. Indeed it was a heap size error. Setting the JAVA_OPTS fixed the problem. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

The key part of your stacktrace, which explains what has broken and why, is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at 
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
```

This is telling us that Java didn't have enough memory allocated to it to store all of the data that processing your file entails

If you need help with increasing your JVM heap size, I would suggest you review [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory), which both talk you through it all.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same exception when reading .xlsx file

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused By :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoadern
```

Then I"ve removed my old xmlbeans-2.0.jar and put the latest [xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeans230jar.htm) containing this method and it is solved now

Comment: This was exactly my problem, although my error was slightly different (wasn't out of memory, but it was the InvocationTargetException). Removing the old xmlbeans worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have inserted `org.apache.xmlbeans` in in project. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others answers:
add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It will work after that.

In fact poi-ooxml needs poi and poi-ooxml-schemas
but 
poi-ooxml-schemas needs xmlbeans

You can see these prerequisites at this page
https://poi.apache.org/overview.html