# Reading .xlsx file using Apache POI gives InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to read .xlsx file using Apache POI, but am getting hit by error:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Full stack trace of error says:

```
    org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:625)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:637)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:186)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:290)
    at com.gemini.util.WorkbookObject.createExcelObj(WorkbookObject.java:77)
    at com.gemini.util.ObjectPool.prepareList(ObjectPool.java:24)
    at com.gemini.util.WorkbookObject.getInstance(WorkbookObject.java:36)
    at dhfl_idecimal.decimal_dhfl.calculator.Calculator.processWealthPlusAce(Calculator.java:33)
    at dhfl_idecimal.decimal_dhfl.calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:167)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:60)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Attribute "type" was already specified for element "v:shape".
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:138)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.<init>(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:121)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 549; Attribute "type" was already specified for element "v:shape".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:137)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMLDrawing.read(XSSFVMLDrawing.java:136)
    ... 16 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dhfl_idecimal.decimal_dhfl.calculator.util.UpdateInput.updateInputParamForWealthPlusAce(UpdateInput.java:23)
    at dhfl_idecimal.decimal_dhfl.calculator.Calculator.processWealthPlusAce(Calculator.java:38)
    at dhfl_idecimal.decimal_dhfl.calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:167)
```

PS: I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364338/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-in-p) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688878/reading-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi-gives-org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-on-linu) questions, but no help.

I also tried adding `org.apache.xmlbeans` jar, but no luck.

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet, which reads a .xlsx file ??

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Not an exact solution but worked. 
There was nothing wrong with my code as I tried reading other excels and it worked flawlessly. The problem was with excel.

**Possible Reason:**
The excel is parsed into XML first and when the XML is invalid you get this error. My excel was primarily developed using MS-Office( Windows environment) and I edited it using Libra Calc (in Linux environment), so this may a reason the `poi` couldn't read the excel properly.
**Solution**: Just developed the same excel in Linux environment as it worked good.