# Exact euclidean Travelling Salesman

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am trying to implement the algorithm to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem.

I know that it is NP-Hard but I only need to solve it for 20 cities.
I want to have an excat result and want to use the dynamic programming algorithm.

With my current implementation I am getting an java heap space error.
This happens because I create an solution matrix with a index of "1 << n".

I can´t find any information related to this problem.
Only found some information for max 10 cities.

Can anyone help me?

This is my code for TSP:

```
 int n = dist.length;
        int[][] dp = new int[n][n];
        for (int[] d : dp)
            Arrays.fill(d, Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
        dp[1][0] = 0;
        for (int mask = 1; mask < 1 << n; mask += 2) {
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if ((mask & 1 << i) != 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        if ((mask & 1 << j) != 0) {
                            dp[mask][i] = Math.min(dp[mask][i], dp[mask ^ (1 << i)][j] + dist[j][i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            res = Math.min(res, dp[(1 << n) - 1][i] + dist[i][0]);
        }

        // reconstruct path
        int cur = (1 << n) - 1;
        int[] order = new int[n];
        int last = 0;
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            int bj = -1;
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                if ((cur & 1 << j) != 0 && (bj == -1 || dp[cur][bj] + dist[bj][last] > dp[cur][j] + dist[j][last])) {
                    bj = j;
                }
            }
            order[i] = bj;
            cur ^= 1 << bj;
            last = bj;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(order));
        return res;
```

Comment: `1 << n` is not too big for `n = 20`. It is simply 1 million, which is fine even when multiplied by `n`. However, you must not allocate it dynamically, just do it statically with your maximum possible `n` instead of creating a new matrix that depends on an input `n`.

Comment: I have tried it with some greater numbers like 23,24 and there I have the OutOfMemory error. I dont understand what you mean with "maximum possible n". As I don´t know how big it will be. Could you explain that please.

Comment: "I only need to solve it for 20 cities" -> if it doesn't need to work for 21 cities, max N is 20.

Comment: If `n` is 20, the code segment provided will take up not much more than a few kilobytes (`dp` is the biggest data structure, taking up around 20*20*4 bytes = 1.6 KB), which obviously shouldn't cause an out-of-memory error. However, when I run the code I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: If you meant `int[1<<n][n]`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory) for how to increase the maximum memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
int[][] dp = new int [1 << n][n];
```

Instead of :

```
int[][] dp = new int [n][n];
```