# Put a 79MB file into couchDB,then out of memory

Tags: couchdb, arrays, out-of-memory

As you know ,couchDB asked for byte array to store file.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) file.length());
```

Then I got a exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:60)
>       at com.erp.util.CouchTest.getBytesFromFile(CouchTest.java:47)

How can I put a large size file into a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this has nothing to do with CouchDB, and is just an issue with the size of your JVM. I'd recommend to have a look at [How can I increase the JVM memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory)