# How to wait till an audio clip is loaded?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm quite a newbie in JAVA and I am trying to read a clip. Here is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class TestClipBis {
protected static AudioFormat audioFormat;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

// Specification of the sound to play
// No control. We assume that the sound can be played on audio system
//File soundFile = new File("chimes.wav");
File soundFile = new File("test.wav");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(soundFile);
InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(is);
//AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

audioFormat = sound.getFormat();
System.out.println(audioFormat);

// Loading the sound into the memory (a Clip)
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
System.out.println(info);
//Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getClip();
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

System.out.println("Sound frame lenght : "+sound.getFrameLength());
System.out.println("Clip FrameLength before opening : "+clip.getFrameLength());
System.out.println("Clip will open - "+info);
System.out.println("Info format : "+info.getLineClass());

// Check before this line that everything is in memory
// Yes, but how ?
clip.open(sound);
System.out.println("Clip is open");
System.out.println("Clip FrameLength after opening : "+clip.getFrameLength());
// Due to a bug in Java Sound,
// we explicitly out of the VM when the sounds stop
clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
  public void update(LineEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        System.out.println("Methode de sortie");
      event.getLine().close();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
});


// Playing the clip
clip.start();

System.out.println("IsActive : "+clip.isActive());
//clip.close();

 }
}
```

My problem is how to be sure that the clip is loaded in memory before opening and playing it ? With the above code, when I open and play the sound file, I have few seconds of playing but never the same length, randomly, and never the full song.

Or should I use something else than a clip to play a song? But I want to "move" into the song and not only streaming it from the start to the end.

Edit:

Ok, I tried few things. First, I tried to see if the "ByteArrayOuptputStream" was written. I had a "println" in the loop and yes, all is written but it don't fix the problem.

Then, when I open the clip, I tried to add the parameters : audioformat, bytearray, startpoint, bufferlength. Nothing better.

Then, I noticed that when the sounds stop, the method to exit was used. So, I tried to "mute" that method (with comment signs). The result is different : it read the file but the sound is jerky. And when I check the CPU use, it's around 100%. Is it a first clue to guess what's the problem ?

I tried to make a loop that indicates the frameposition after the start : all the frames are read but the sound is still jerky.
I also tried the thead.sleep before and after the start method : nothing better.

So, here is the code I use. Many code parts are between "comment quotes" because they are try, unsuccessfull...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class TestBufferedClip {
protected static AudioFormat audioFormat;
public static ByteBuffer buffer;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

// Specification of the sound to play
// No control. We assume that the sound can be played on audio system
//File soundFile = new File("chimes.wav");
File soundFile = new File("test.wav");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(soundFile);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int)soundFile.length());

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
int loop = 0;
while ((n=fis.read(buf))>=0) {
    baos.write(buf);
    buf=new byte[1024];
    System.out.println("Loop = "+loop);
    loop+=1;
}
byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();
System.out.println("ByteArray size : "+ba.length);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);

//AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bais);
audioFormat = sound.getFormat();
System.out.println(audioFormat);

// Loading the sound into the memory (a Clip)
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
System.out.println("Info :"+info);
//Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getClip();
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

System.out.println("Sound frame lenght : "+sound.getFrameLength());
System.out.println("Info format : "+info.getLineClass());

// Check before this line that everything is in memory
// Yes, but how ?
clip.open(audioFormat, ba, 0, ba.length);
//clip.open(sound);
System.out.println("Clip is open");
System.out.println("Clip FrameLength after opening : "+clip.getFrameLength());
// Due to a bug in Java Sound,
// we explicitly out of the VM when the sounds stop
/*
clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
  public void update(LineEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        System.out.println("Methode de sortie");
      event.getLine().close();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
});
*/

// Playing the clip
System.out.println("Before thread sleep");
try {
    Thread.sleep(31000);
} catch (InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("After thread sleep");

clip.start();

System.out.println("IsActive : "+clip.isActive());
/*
while (clip.isActive()==true) {
    System.out.println("Position = "+clip.getFramePosition());
}
*/
//clip.close();

}
}
```

@Phil Freihofner :
I thought about your solution to read and discards data until I reach my "start" point. You wrote "In order to start at a point within the audio file, using a SourceDataLine, you would have to read and discard data from the audio input line until you got to the desired starting spot". How do you do that ? When I use the "SourceDataLine" method, my start method is a loop with a line.write(bytes, 0, bytesreads); to point the sound on the speakers.
So, how do you just read and discard ? I didn't find any "read" method with the line.

Comment: Sound data can be progressively read from an AudioInputStream? When you read the data that way, just read it into a variable over and over (over-writing) until you get to the desired starting point. Then and only then do you start shipping the data from the AIS to the SourceDataLine write command. There is a code example of AudioInputStream -> SourceDataLine in the Java tutorials on this link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html Search for the phrase "do something useful" and it should drop you into a comment of a good code example (first full code example on page).

Comment: Great !!! Your solution is perfect. I'll give up the solution of the audioclip. It seems too complicated when I used an openJDK with Linux. And your solution works very well. So, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javax.sound.sampled supports two objects for playing back audio. The Clip, as you are using, has to be loaded completely into memory before one can play it back. On the plus side, it is also easy to position the playback to start from within the Clip, either using microseconds or frame position.

I see no benefit from first loading the sound into a byte buffer. That is a redundant level of buffering for Clips. I'd only do it if you were trying to do DSP or something else that requires getting to the data, something beyond the Clip's built in ability to set a start point.

If you are able to preload the possible audio choices as Clips before they are selected, that might be the best solution, as long as you don't run out of RAM.

The other option for playback is a SourceDataLine. It reads and plays back the file on a per-buffer basis. Thus, it can start up quicker than an unloaded Clip (no need to load the entire file into memory first). However, once the Clip is preloaded, the Clip will play back without having to do repeated file loads.

In order to start at a point within the audio file, using a SourceDataLine, you would have to read and discard data from the audio input line until you got to the desired starting spot. You can do this by counting frames (the format will tell you the number of bytes per frame). This reading and discarding would disrupt timing a bit, but my experience has been that reading and discarding audio data is a couple of orders of magnitude faster than playback, since playback involves blocking queues to keep the output at the required frame rate.

Check the [Java Sound Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html) for more info, which includes links to the Clip and SourceDataLine APIs.

Here is an example of the loading of a Clip:

```
File soundFile = new File("test.wav");
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(sound);
```

The data from test.wav should now be in RAM. All that other stuff you have using byte buffers and buffered lines is unnecessary.

When you are ready to play, use clip.setMicrosecondPosition(long milliseconds) to set your sound to start at the desired location, (not needed if you are starting from the beginning, unless you've already played the Clip, in which case the position will be where it was when you stopped). Then use clip.start() to commence playing.

IMPORTANT NOTE: playback will end prematurely if the program running it exits. One way to test this is to put a Thread.sleep(long milliseconds) command after the clip.start(), where the value of milliseconds is longer than the length of the clip. But that is not a real solution, just a diagnostic to prevent the program from closing the clip playback thread. You should be handling keeping the program running from the main threads, not the thread with the audio playback.

Comment: I try to use the clip (see the firt code I posted) but it seems it don't preload the whole clip before starting to play. So, it starts to play sound and stop after only few seconds (usually from 1 to 10 seconds, randomly). And I read at that place (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874361/clip-plays-wav-file-with-bad-lag-in-java) that my problem could be that clip have to be loaded into memory before it starts. Yes, ok... but how ?

Comment: I added info on properly opening a Clip (this is the pre-loading step), in the main answer.

Answer (score 0):

First read whole into a byte buffer. Do this by copying all content from file to `ByteArrayOutputStream`. This way you will have whole media content in memory. Now you can wrap array from `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` into `ByteArrayInputStream` and provide that pure in-memory stream as audio input stream.