# "insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment " message in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run my Java code in Eclipse, I get the following message:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 4088 bytes for AllocateHeap
An error report file with more information is saved as:
E:\Eclipse_Workspace\BTest\hs_err_pid1888.log
```

I have 4GB RAM in my computer.  I have changed my JRE from 1.7 to 1.8 too. But the issue seems un-resolved. I use a Win 8 system with i3 Processor and have around 20gb of free disk space in my C Drive.

Eclipse version: Eclipse Juno Service release 2

I also get this message while starting Eclipse. I have attached the error message screen shot.

What is causing this issue?

[image]

**Memory parameters in "eclipse.ini" file:**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

**Resolution:**
Re-installing eclipse fixed the problem.

Comment: is this happen only when you are using eclipse?

Comment: Have you try to edit your eclipse jvm properties in **eclipse.ini** (in your eclipse folder) to allocate more memory to eclipse ?

Comment: Increasing the virtual memory may solve the issue. Possibly your system is affected with virus.!!

Comment: @Rafa El: Yes,when i started Netbeans,i don't come across any such message.

Comment: @Balaram26 Request to let us know what are the memory parameters specified in your eclipse.in?

Comment: Your application (Eclipse) needs more memory and JVM is not allocating enough.You can increase the amount of memory JVM allocates by following the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory)

Answer (score 80):

The message above means that you're running so many programs on your PC that there is no memory left to run one more. This isn't a Java problem and no Java option is going to change this.

Use the Task Manager of Windows to see how much of your 4GB RAM is actually **free**. My guess is that somewhere, you have a program that eats all the memory. Find it and kill it.

**EDIT** You need to understand that there are two types of "out of memory" errors.

The first one is the OutOfMemoryException which you get when Java code is running and the Java *heap* is not large enough. This means Java *code* asks the Java *runtime* for memory. You can fix those with `-Xmx...`

The other error is when the Java *runtime* runs out of memory. This isn't related to the Java heap *at all*. This is an error when Java asks the OS for more memory and the OS says: "Sorry, I don't have any."

To fix the latter, close applications or reboot (to clean up memory fragmentation).

Comment: but that doesn't explain why the above message appears only when using eclipse, I guess

Comment: @RafaEl: The above error message isn't printed by Eclipse itself. The first error originates from a unit test run **inside** of Eclipse (so Eclipse might be eating all the memory) and the second one is from Windows *before* Eclipse can even be started.

Comment: perhaps you are correct, but as OP stated in comment _"when i started Netbeans, i don't come across any such message"_ which as far as I know, Netbeans require more memory(approximately `400mb`) compare to Eclipse(`200mb`)

Comment: I did check with the Task manager at the beginning of this issue. The maximum memory used was only 502mb. But after starting the eclipse,the cpu usage went to nearly 85% and above ,which was weird.

Comment: @AaronDigulla yes,you are correct. The two messages where from two different sources. But they all end up saying that there not enough memory with the JVM.  I specifically use eclipse,because it takes less memory than netbeans. and this behaviour is unusual to me. I have check the system for viruses,for unknown process running. But ended up empty.

Comment: See my edits. None of the errors are because of Java running out of heap space.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Give us information and we might be able to help.

Comment: There is no OutOfMemoryException class in JDK documentation. There is only java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 16):

How to diagnose this error even when running the simple command:

```
java -version
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home2/ericlesc/code/java/c2/hs_err_pid23944.log
```

Check the amount of free memory you have:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         28119      26643       1475        189       2391      15368
-/+ buffers/cache:       8884      19235
Swap:         5117         34       5083
```

**Check the max number of user processes, make sure you are not over limit:**

```
ulimit -a

ps -ef | wc -l
```

For me, the reason this happened was because PHP had consumed too much memory allocated to me on bluehost, and the way I was able to fix it, without restarting PHP or the server ( I can't ) was to take the `public_html` directory and rename it.  And give it a minute for PHP to see the change, then rename it back.

A bug in the php engine itself.  I found a clever way to give the PHP engine a swift kick.

**(update Feb 2016)** (I'm getting a spike of up-votes on this because Bluehost instance PHP engines are reserving all the memory and leaving none for the JVM.  In their defense, PHP is evolving into an unholy rube Goldberg machine.  Bluehost as a service is on the decline.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite simple to fix, I am not sure why no one mentioned the actual working solution.

Firstly, make sure, **Wireless Hotspot** is Turned Off. That's most important, while building the Project, the Hotspot must not be On.

Do this, and Thanks me later

[image: Follow the image to set your environment variables.]

Secondly, set the **Environment Variables** into your system, and Thirdly **disable the firewall** or antivirus for Android Studio & Java VM. It will definately fix your issue.

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 291 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 5 s 664 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 210 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 7 s 258 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on ec2 and wanted to do mvn build then use -T option which tells maven to use number of threads while doing build

eg:`mvn -T 10 clean package`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Virtual Machine (VM), **allocate more RAM to your VM** and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Eclipse` installation directory you should be able to find the file `eclipse.ini`. Open it and find the `-vmargs` section. Adjust the value of:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

In this example it is set to 1GB.

Comment: This will only increase the heap. It possibly won't affect windows in any way.!!

Comment: Also this is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But After changing it also,i am getting the same message.

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify your eclipse.ini with below

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms2G
-Xmx3G
-XX:MaxPermSize=2G
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Once you open your eclipse you can try below

Looks like your application consumes more memory than allocated (Default). I will try two things

1. As suggested by Harmlezz increase your memory allocation to JVM to -Xms2g -Xmx2g (If needed increase it more and try it out)
2. Download eclipse memory analyzer and check for what causing memory leak OR even you can use JConsole to see JVM memory utilization in order to figure out application memory leak issue.

Comment: If suggestion 1 doesn't work you should try permutation and combination for java hotspots http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as i have said in my update,I downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse(Kepler) and installed the scala plugins,then compiled my application,there was no error message of any sort displayed. So i think based on this,the error cannot be in my memory allocation or with my JVM.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that I manually set the Windows virtual memory too low to save space in the system SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to diagnosis the jvm usages like how many process is running and what about heap allocation. there exists a lot of ways to do that for example

- you can use java jcmd to check number of object, size of memory (for linux you can use for example "/usr/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/jcmd 19628 GC.class_histogram > /tmp/19628_ClassHistogram_1.txt", here 19628 is the running application process id). You can easily check if any strong reference exists in your code or else.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question talking about eclipse but i got the similar issue many times with Intellij as well and the solution for it was easy .. Just run the 64 bit exe not the 32 one which is always the default one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that the C: drive was out of space. Ensure that you have enough space available.