# Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue in java application

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have quartz scheduler that runs 24 hours in background.
Now I am not even able to run normal application. It gives me the above error.

Scheduler Description:

There is a scheduler. It run every 2 hours and calls a job class. Job class fetches a list of client and sync all the data of each client from one system to another. For each client, this process takes maximum 10 minutes. I have added the scheduler in web.xml file inside listener tag.

Can anyone let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment " message in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805552/insufficient-memory-for-the-java-runtime-environment-message-in-eclipse)

Comment: You give very little details, so everything is guesswork. It could be that your quartz scheduler starts background processes that never finish and so use up all resources of your computer.

Comment: Please provide more details about the applications that are running and the load that you are generating on the server

Comment: Please check above. I have edited my post with description of what my scheduler does.

Answer (score -1):

The message above means that you're running so many programs on your PC that there is no memory left to run one more. This isn't a Java problem and no Java option is going to change this.

Use the Task Manager of Windows to see how much of your 4GB RAM is actually free. My guess is that somewhere, you have a program that eats all the memory. Find it and kill it.

Comment: I have killed the tomcat instance and restarted. Now it is working fine. Can you tell me why do this problem occur?

Comment: If this answer helped you please mark this answer as the one it solved your question