# How to increase JVM Runtime Memory in windows

Tags: cmd, jmeter

I am trying to run the script through command line for that I am using below command

```
 C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -f -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\CSVDATATest.csv
```

But It gives below Error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x05400000, 1073741824, 0) failed; error='The paging file is too small for this operation to complet e' (DOS error/errno=1455)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824 bytes for Failed 
to commit area from 0x05400000 to 0x45400000 of length 1073741824.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\hs_err_pid2076.log
 errorlevel=1 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Your system's RAM might already be occupied by other open applications. Close other unnecessary application while running JMeter app. Refer for more detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805552/insufficient-memory-for-the-java-runtime-environment-message-in-eclipse?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Can you show content of C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\hs_err_pid2076.log ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the error you're getting:

> The paging file is too small for this operation to complete

You need to increase size of virtual memory (swap file), see [How to Change The Size of Virtual Memory (pagefile.sys) on Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2013/01/how-to-change-the-size-of-virtual-memory-pagefile-sys-on-windows-8-or-windows-server-2012/) guide for more details.

---

However be aware that using swap will dramatically negatively impact JMeter's performance so if you're running out of available physical RAM it is better to consider [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) - i.e. run JMeter slaves on multiple hosts as most likely you won't be able to create the required load from a single machine.

References:

- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: the link is not working. please check.

hello good people, you can also follow this link: https://itproguru.com/expert/2013/01/how-to-change-the-size-of-virtual-memory-pagefile-sys-on-windows-8-or-windows-server-2012/

Answer (score 3):

You can assign `80%` of your memory to the JMeter and for that you need to enter below line to jmeter.bat file

```
Set HEAP=-Xms1024m –Xmx3072m [If you have 4 GB Ram]
```

You can adjust above heap size based on physical memory of your machine.

Comment: thanks for your reply this works fine for heap dump issue.