# Android studio Gradle Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I wanted to try out android studio but when i create a project i get this error:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\laszl\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7.1-bin\bwlcbys1h7rz3272sye1xwiv6\gradle-6.7.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000080000000, 268435456, 0) failed; error='The paging file is too small for this operation to complete' (DOS error/errno=1455)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 268435456 bytes for Failed to commit area from 0x0000000080000000 to 0x0000000090000000 of length 268435456.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\laszl\.gradle\daemon\6.7.1\hs_err_pid30736.log

-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
 - gradle.properties in project root directory
```

As far as i can see i need more memory but i have 16gb ram and android studio is already using 12gb.

Answer (score 1):

JVM uses something called a `heap` to decide how much memory it is going to take while it performs the necessary tasks. You can consider it something like a place for keeping user defined datatypes at runtime.It is similar to RAM but not quite

**Two solutions**

1. You can manage your heap space for larger projects using [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#adjusting_heap_size) gui based way
2. If you prefer the non gui way,which is always more reliable, this is a sample `gradle.properties` file I am attaching from one of my projects
   Note that the `1024m` specifies the amount of RAM to be be given to JVM for the heap storage(1024MB). You can double it in your case, i.e . 2048M or even triple it

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
org.gradle.daemon=true
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx7g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I have tried both solutions but it till uses all my ram and gives the same error.

Comment: Hey @ptm.rankzy please check if all other applications are closed because Android studio should not use that much RAM , there is definitely something else running

Also please post the content of `C:\Users\laszl\.gradle\daemon\6.7.1\hs_err_pid30736.log`.

If none of these work then, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506141/how-to-increase-jvm-runtime-memory-in-windows)