# Tomcat 8 when stated in ec2 machine

Tags: java, linux, tomcat8

This is my scenario:

1. SWAP Memory avaiable: 4GB
2. Linux

I'm getting these warnings:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit ServerVM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000540000000, 7158628352, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Also this error:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 7158628352 bytes for committing reserved memory.
 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/hs_err_pid8656.log
```

ram memory in my machine:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7986       7839        147          0         94       1390
-/+ buffers/cache:       6354       1632
Swap:         4095          3       4092


WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"..
```

Comment: Add more details to the question. Linux version, RAM amount, also post the conent of the file located in `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/hs_err_pid8656.log`. Some details on your tomcat8 configuration, and maybe some details about the usage of your swap (on linux teminal use: `htop` or `top`

Comment: The first warning is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize) that explain the deprecation of the option `MaxPermSize`. The second warning is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002612/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning). About the error I suggest to you to check your ram usage as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547225/5532710) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805787/5532710)

Comment: WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"
with this warning i have changed my username and password in my tomcat_user.xml and restarted my instance.

Comment: As you can see here `Mem:          7986       7839        147          0         94       1390` your ram is full. You have free swap but if your JVM start use the swap performance will drop through the floor if that happens.