# Ionic Android Build failed : Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, jvm

when i'm running `ionic build android --release` 
i get an error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Does anyone know the fix ?[image]

Comment: no sure this might help : you can configure heap size in vm settings .. try that .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory

Comment: uninstall existing 32 bit JDK. this JDK by default installed in program files x86. now download (https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-windows-x64.exe) and install 64 bit. by default it will install in program files. that's it

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I got the solution by adding a new system variable `name : _JAVA_OPTIONS` and `value : -Xmx512M`

Comment: Remember to restart your CMD

Comment: Thank you, Amit Singh very much appreciated. And @anokrize , that also helped.

Comment: If you don't want to restart the command prompt, also add the variable to the current session with: SET _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME!! I had this issue for days. Why is this little setting not recorded anywhere?

Comment: Man you saved my day. I was stuck for hours trying to compiling, after a lot of issues that i had to solve you gave me the last tip to finally compile succesfully, thank you very much, i was desperate

Answer (score 6):

After changing the setting in the environment you should restart your Command Prompt CMD to update environment variables

Answer (score 0):

your solution: I got the solution by adding a new system variable name : _JAVA_OPTIONS and value : -Xmx512M
Hi Amit **where should I change this**

Comment: Add a new system variable by name _JAVA_OPTIONS and value -Xmx512M

Comment: Hi Amit Thank you it works for me. I am facing this problem from last 2 days.