# gradle keeps failing. Cordova run. Vscode

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have all environment paths set correctly. I tried to manually change jvm number in the gradle.properties file in vscode but when i run cordova it resets automatically. When i run a cordova requirements check in vscode terminal, it all checks out good, but when i go to run Cordova I get this error.

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\cordova>  cordova run
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\lilbubba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\lilbubba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\lilbubba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\lilbubba\Downloads\gradle-6.4.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.4.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.4.1

I tried to change gradle from 8.6 to 6.4 to be compatible with java 1.8 but it still doesn't work. I have sdk's 33, 32, and 14 on my computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic Android Build failed : Unable to start the daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385165/ionic-android-build-failed-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process)